# webapp2 - read-only file system error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I'm developing a Google App Engine app using Python (webapp2) & Jinja2 and I'm trying to create a **PDF** file using the **[reportlab](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab)** library.

Example:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

class pdf(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    x = 50
    y = 750
    c = canvas.Canvas("file.pdf")
    c.drawString(x*5,y,"Output")
    c.line(x,y-10,x*11,y-10)
    c.save()
```

When I run the server I'm getting the following error:

```
raise IOError(errno.EROFS, 'Read-only file system', filename)
IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: u'file.pdf'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by using [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html):

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

# Import String IO which is a
# module that reads and writes a string buffer
# cStringIO is a faster version of StringIO
from cStringIO import StringIO

class pdf(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    pdfFile = StringIO()

    x = 50
    y = 750
    c = canvas.Canvas(pdfFile)
    c.drawString(x*5,y,"Output")
    c.line(x,y-10,x*11,y-10)
    c.save()

    self.response.headers['content-type'] = 'application/pdf'
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.pdf'
    self.response.out.write(pdfFile.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't write to the appengine filesystem -- After all, since you have multiple machines (and you can't guanrantee the same ones all the time), which machine's filesystem would you write to?

However, it looks like the reportlab canvas accepts an open file object.  I can't guarantee that this will work, but you can try passing an open file-like object instead.  e.g. [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) or even `webapp2.Response.out`.

```
import io
class pdf(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    x = 50
    y = 750
    c = canvas.Canvas(self.response.out)
    c.drawString(x*5,y,"Output")
    c.line(x,y-10,x*11,y-10)
    c.save()
```

Comment: Duh ... Sorry, I meant the `webapp2.Response` object, not the `webapp2.Request` object...

Comment: This is the right approach anyway, even if you could write to the filesystem. Otherwise, what would happen if you had multiple requests for PDFs at the same time?